# Summing up series which is similar to Taylor expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am given series as 
$$S= \frac{1.2.3}{1!} + \frac{2.3.4}{2!} + \frac{3.4.5}{3!}+.........$$ 
I know this series looks similar to $e^x$ expansion and probably $x=1$ here so how to express my series in terms of $e$  ? I am unable to separate out numbers from numerator to look it like $e$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Manipulate the series to show that
$$\sum\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)x^n}{n!}=(x^2(x^2e^x)')'=e^xx^2(x^2+6x+6)$$
and then evaluate at $x=1$:
$$\sum\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{n!}=13e$$

> When you take derivative of $$e^x=\sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ you get $$e^x=\sum\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$$ If you multiply by $x^2$ you get $$x^2e^x=\sum\frac{nx^{n+1}}{n!}$$ which makes the exponent of the $x$ ready for the next derivative to spit the factor $(n+1)$. After that derivative you multiply again by $x^2$ to get the exponent $x^{n+2}$, which produces the factor $(n+2)$ after taking the next derivative.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you did in first step? What does  prime represent ? And how that quadratic came ?

Comment: This is genius , amazing.

Comment: @Tesla No, far from it. These are [manipulations of power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties) that people use a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If:
$$ S = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{n!} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(m+3)(m+2)}{m!} $$
then:
$$ S = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{m^2}{m!}+5\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{m}{m!}+6\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{m!} $$
where:
$$ \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{m}{m!} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!} = e, $$
$$ \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{m^2}{m!} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n+1}{n!} = 2e, $$
hence:
$$ S = 2e+5e+6e = \color{red}{13 e}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Pp..'s answer, let us consider first $$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{n!}x^n$$ and let us write $$n(n+1)(n+2)=An(n-1)(n-2)+Bn(n-1)+Cn$$ (even if it is clear that $A$=1). Expanding both lhs and rhs and grouping powers $$n (-2 A+B-C+2)+n^2 (3 A-B+3)+(1-A) n^3=0$$ So, solving the linear equations, $A=1$, $B=6$, $C=6$. So, without changing anything $$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n!}x^n+6\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}x^n+6\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}x^n$$ $$S_2=x^3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n!}x^{n-3}+6x^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}x^{n-2}+6x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}x^{n-1}$$ $$S_2=x^3 (e^x)'''+6x^2(e^x)''+6x(e^x)'=e^x(x^3+6x^2+6x)$$ An identical process would apply to $$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+p)}{n!}x^n$$ and lead to $$S_3=e^x \left(x^4+12 x^3+36 x^2+24 x\right)$$ $$S_4=e^x \left(x^5+20 x^4+120 x^3+240 x^2+120 x\right)$$ $$S_5=e^x \left(x^6+30 x^5+300 x^4+1200 x^3+1800 x^2+720 x\right)$$ $$S_6=e^x \left(x^7+42 x^6+630 x^5+4200 x^4+12600 x^3+15120 x^2+5040 x\right)$$ $$S_7=e^x \left(x^8+56 x^7+1176 x^6+11760 x^5+58800 x^4+141120 x^3+141120 x^2+40320
   x\right)$$ For $x=1$, the terms for $S_0$ to $S_7$ will then be $e,3e,13e$, $73e$, $501e$, $4051e$, $37633e$, $394353e$. The coefficients of $e$ corresponds to sequence $A000262$ at $OEIS$.